# PHP (while, date_diff)

Tags: php, date, while-loop

I have a past date of appointment set.
Every new appointment is 8 days apart from the previous (past appointment+8 days).
I would like to create a simple script to return the dates of appointments for the next 365 days starting from the current day each time (i.e. 0=< interval (today-appointment) =< 365).

I've tried something like this but I don't get what I want:

```
  <?php 
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

    $today = new DateTime("now");
    $appointment=new DateTime('2013-08-26');
    $interval = $appointment->diff($today)->d; 

    while ($interval <= 365 && $interval => 0)
    {
       echo $appointment->format('l n F Y');
       $appointment->add(new DateInterval('P8D'));
    } ?>
```

Comment: I don't think =< is proper, <= is. Not sure if that's your problem, but it is a problem.

Comment: Try **+8D** instead of **P8D**

Comment: `Increment or Decrement` `$interval` to `exit or break` the `loop`, its looking `infinite loop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum from your question :

1. starting next new appointment is first date from today, that is on `+8 day interval` from appointment in the past;
2. every next appointment is `+8 days` from previous one;
3. show appointments only between `today` and `today+365days` interval;

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

$today = new DateTime('today');
$appointment = new DateTime('2013-08-23');
$next_appointment_in_days = ceil($appointment->diff($today)->days / 8) * 8;
$next_appointment = clone $appointment;
$next_appointment->modify("+$next_appointment_in_days day");

do {
    echo $next_appointment->format('l, j F Y') . "\n";
    $next_appointment->modify('+8 day');
} while ($today->diff($next_appointment)->days <= 365);
```

[Run this code.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/spig1O)

Comment: Thank you so much! This really did what I was unsuccessfully trying. Thanks again.

Comment: @PattySmith: np mate.